# Visual Studio 2019 breaking on external exceptions despite "Just My Code" enabled

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2019

I have `Break on all exceptions` checked under "Exception Settings". I also have "Enable Just My Code" checked under Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General.

Despite this, Visual Studio is breaking on exceptions in third party library code, and showing me things like this:

[image]

How can I get rid of that? I want to break on all exceptions in just my code.

Comment: @HansPassant Not sure I know where you mean. I have no "Modules" under Debug -> Windows

Comment: Ah yes. Found it! So what does this mean? :D

Answer (score 0):

For me this was the solution. The problem appeared after having debugged a DMP file.
[image]